# Elixir and Gulp - Copy and concatenate

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

How can I copy and concatenate multiple JS files?

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
    .copy([
            'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
            'node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js'
        ],
        'public/js/plugins.js'
    );
```

But only the later file (magnific-popup.js) is output to plugins.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mix.scripts` rather than `copy`:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts(
        // Source files
        [
            'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
            'node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js'
        ],
        // Destination
        'public/js/plugins.js'
    );
});
```

Comment: Ah! Yes, thank you. Had to alter the source file paths slightly (`../../../node_modules/etc`) but all working now.